# c++ code type substition fail

Tags: c++, oop

I have this code, but is impossible to compile with g++ or msvc. I am trying to make a custom type CharNw that I can use it as string, in existing all string routines or pass as argument  all existing functions:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void fx(unsigned int x)
{
 /*this is the reason of all this 
 but is ok,  not is problem here */
.....
}
class CharNw
{   
    int wt;
    char cr;

public:
    CharNw() { wt = -1; cr = '\0'; }
    CharNw( char c) { if wt > 0 fx( (unsigned int) wt); cr = c; }
    operator char () { if wt > 0 fx( (unsigned int) wt); return cr ;}
    assgn( int f) { wt = f;}
};
int main(void)
{
CharNw hs[40];          //it is ok
CharNw tf[] = "This is not working, Why?\n";
char dst[40];
    strcpy(dst, tf); //impossible to compile
printf("dst = %s, tf = %s", dst, tf); //too
return 0;
}
```

Can help me?

Comment: Using a valid syntax would be a good first step. This code is rubbish.

Comment: You have nothing that converts *a pointer to char* to an array of `CharNw`.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Don't use C-Style string related functions with your `CharNw` class, not compatible.  Since you are using C++, prefer to derive a `class StringNw` from `std::basic_string`, e.g. `class StringNw : public std::basic_string<CharNw>`.  Follow the example for wide strings, [a.k.a. `wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 0):

Line by line.

```
CharNw hs[40];          //it is ok
```

The above is an array of `CharNw` objects with a capacity of 40 elements.  This is good.

```
CharNw tf[] = "This is not working, Why?\n";
```

On the right hand side (RHS) of the assignment, you have a type `char const * const* and on the left you have an array of`CharNw`.  The`CharNw` is not a character, so you have a problem here.  Prefer to have both sides of an assignment to have the same type.

```
char dst[40];
```

An array of *characters*.  Nothing more, nothing less.  It has a capacity of 40 characters.  **The `dst` array is not a string.**  You should prefer to use `#define` for your array capacities.

```
    strcpy(dst, tf); //impossible to compile
```

The `strcpy` requires both parameters to be pointers to `char`.  The left parameter can be decomposed to a pointer to the first `char` of the array.  The `tf` is an **array of `CharNw`** which is not compatible with an array of `char` nor a pointer to `char`.

```
printf("dst = %s, tf = %s", dst, tf); //too
```

The `printf` *format specifier* `%s` requires a pointer to a character, preferably a C-Style, nul terminated array (or sequence) of characters.  The `tf` parameter is an array of `CharNw` which is not an array of characters nor a pointer to a single character or a C-Style string.

**Edit 1: Conversion Operators**
The method `operator char ()` in your class converts a character variable to a `CharNw` variable.  **It does not apply to pointers nor arrays.**
You would need some messy pointer conversion functions.

Here is an examples:

```
const unsigned int ARRAY_CAPACITY = 40U;
const char text[] = "I am Sam.  Sam I am."
CharNw tf[ARRAY_CAPACITY];
for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < sizeof(text); ++i)
{
  tf[i] = text[i];  // OK, Converts via constructor.
}
for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < sizeof(text); ++i)
{
  printf("%c", tf[i]);  // The tf[i] should use the operator char () method.
}
```

A better approach is to declare a class using `std::basic_string`, rather than trying to squeeze your class into the C-Style string functions.

For example:

```
class StringNw : public std::basic_string<CharNw>
{
};
```